# Why flink kafka source in table api can't merge?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have several jobs to merge. Because their data source is the same. So I want to merge them like picture shown below.

[image]

I'm very sure their source is used the same table object. 
I've checked the source code of flink, but didn't help.

Is there any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the DataStream API you can simply do something like this:

```
streamFromKafka = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(inputTopic, ...));

streamFromKafka
  ... // one set of operations
  .addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(outputTopic1, ...));

streamFromKafka
  ... // another set of operations
  .addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(outputTopic2, ...));
```

You'll have to adjust this a bit to use the table API, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Because that's a Kafka source, and I have so many jobs to merge. If each job keep its source, it's no help to reduce network IO to Kafka.